# X11: ^C drop to shell while start X

Tags: xorg, startx, xinit

I use xinit to start X with wm - startx command that using `.xinitrc` to invoke X11 environment, but when X starts, there a black screen with cursor staying there for few seconds before X is fully started and if I press `ctrl-c` to interrupt the process, it will drop to shell, meaning user always has a way to go into shell - how to disable this ability?

Comment: Did you try `wm - startx &` to run it as a background task?

Comment: @Zhro: I just use `.profile` to `startx`, what's difference with your command? I'll try and give feedback.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you're calling `startx` in the foreground. If you want it to run in the background and not be susceptible to `ctrl-c` then append `&` at the end of the command.

For example:

```
sleep 3s && echo 1
```

This command will sleep for three seconds and then echo `1` to standard output. As it is in the foreground, you can interrupt it with `ctrl-c`.

Alternatively, you can continue to work on other things in the foreground while it runs in the background until either you log out or it terminates:

```
sleep 3s && echo 1 &
```

See here for more examples:

https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-jobs-command-examples-usage-syntax/

If you are just running `startx` then try replacing it with `startx &`.